# JIRA plugin to view previous issue status

Tags: history, jira, status, issue-tracking, jira-plugin

I am looking for a JIRA plugin that will show the status of issues at a previous date I give it.  So if I tell it Monday of last week, I would like all of the issues that existed at that time with their status at that time.  I was wondering if such a plugin existed or if there is another way to go about this.  Thanks for reading and for any help you provide.

*Note, I made a excel macro to basically do this but it includes a gigantic mysql query that I would not like not to use if such a plugin already exists.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that such a plugin exists at all because this would involve issue statistics to show how the issue changed over time.

You can post an feature request with the Atlassian JIRA team to see if this is possible or not. They could also include this feature in a future release or a proprietary plugin if they see that there is enough interest.

http://www.atlassian.com/resources/support

Comment: That's what my Timecharts plugin did. It hasn't been updated since 4.2 though.

Comment: Well contact Atlassian support and sort that one out with them as I suggested.